# Inverse of a non-squared matrix working on a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a topological manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $m < n$. Let $W$ be a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ (or $m \times n$ matrix). Assume that $W$ is one-to-one on $A$. Therefore, there is an inverse mapping $W^{-1}: W(A) \to A$. How can I compute this mapping?

Comment: Select a basis of $A$ and invert the matrix representation of $f$...

Comment: What happens when $A$ is a manifold?
And how do you invert a non-squared matrix?

Comment: subspace in context of linear algebra is always a linear subspace. If you have something different in mind, you might want to update your question.

Comment: OK. I just editted it.

Comment: can you give an example for $A$ and $W$? I can't imagine one right now.

Comment: $A = \{(x,x^3)\}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$, $W = (1,1;0,0)$. Then, $W\cdot (x,x^3)^{\top} = (x+x^3,0)$. There is a one-to-one correspondence between $x$ and $x+x^3$. Therefore, $W$ is invertible between the manifolds $A$ and $W(A)$.

Comment: the dimension assumption doesn't match, but I got the idea. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. So, you can ignore the second row of $W$, right?